# want to print a data according to row in text file

Tags: java

I have a text file of data like this

```
username=Ayyappa,password=123
username=venkata,password=456
username=Bhargav,password=789
username=Rama,password=158
username=Pusarla,password=968
```

i want to print the data at row number 2 
(My expected output is username=venkata,password=456)

**Funtion written:**

```
public class TestDataReader {
public static String getrowvalue(String FileName, int rownum) throws IOException{

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(FileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String lineString = null;
        while((lineString = br.readLine())!= null){
            int counter = 1;
            if(counter == rownum){
                System.out.println(lineString);
                counter ++;
            }
        }

        return lineString;
    }

}
```

i called this function in another class

**TestDataReader.getrowvalue("F:\WS_Finsys_Ayyappa\Ejagruti\TestData\login.txt", 2);**

but when i am calling this function it is printing all the row data but not with row data i passed in this case i passed rownum 2 to get the row data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here: you simply flush `counter` value each time in loop:

```
int counter = 1;
```

So change it to:

```
 int counter = 1;
 while((lineString = br.readLine())!= null){
        if(counter == rownum){
            System.out.println(lineString);
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

**UPD**: Also, as @Lemm Ras mentioned, you have to move `counter` incrementation outside `if` statement.

Comment: Also the counter should be incremented outside the _if_ condition, otherwise it will be never/wrongly updated.

Comment: I think the String "lineString" also should be returned as soon as as the couter equals rownum according to the method `getrowvalue`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me,sorry i was not able to think this small mistake

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 solution:

**For small files:**

```
String line32 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt")).get(32)
```

**For large files:**

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    line32 = lines.skip(31).findFirst().get();
}
```

A simple one ,Java <8 solution:

```
public String readLine(int line){
        FileReader tempFileReader = null;
        BufferedReader tempBufferedReader = null;
        try { tempFileReader = new FileReader(textFile); 
        tempBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(tempFileReader);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        String returnStr = "ERROR";
        for(int i = 0; i < line - 1; i++){
            try { tempBufferedReader.readLine(); } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
        try { returnStr = tempBufferedReader.readLine(); }  catch (Exception e) { }

        return returnStr;
    }
```